# how to display xml in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

As the question says, it just escaped my memory how to display xml in javascript, I want to display some source xml within an div on a page, that sits next to the processed result of the xml in another div.

Can't remember if there was an equivalent to javascript's escape to convert entities on the client

**Note**: the xml files are served as is from the server, so I need a client side solution

**Note**: the main problem is XML doesn't render correctly in most browsers, all the brackets and attributes disappear, leaving you with text that doesn't look like xml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the *browser to render* your `XML` as `XML`, it must be in it's own document, like an `iframe`, or a `frame`. `DIV` won't do the job!

Besides, in the `HTTP` header of the request that serves the `iframe` you should send `Content-Type: text/xml`, so the Browser can understand that this content is an `XML`.

But, if you truely need to see it in a DIV you will have to build yourself an `XML` rendering function `XML2HTML`. You can use the `HTML` [`PRE`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_pre.asp) tag for that, if your `XML` string is already formatted (line breaks and tabs). In that case you will have to replace `<` to `&gt;` in the `XML` string.

**Conclusion:** `The browser` can't render `XML` and `HTML` in the same document. If you need it, you just have to workaround it.

Comment: Internet Explorer can render both XML and HTML in the same document, just embed the XML in an <xmp></xmp> tag. Not a recommendation as I believe it's depracated (and of course only works in IE), just an FYI.

Comment: Also note that a DIV can display XML just fine, assuming it is properly encoded. At a minimum, I would suggest encoding > (>), < (<), and & (&amp;).

Answer (score 13):

Fetch your XML using Ajax and simply put the result in a `textarea`. Style the textarea any way you want.

Comment: How does one style XML for example?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a function for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function xml_to_string(xml_node)
    {
        if (xml_node.xml)
            return xml_node.xml;
        else if (XMLSerializer)
        {
            var xml_serializer = new XMLSerializer();
            return xml_serializer.serializeToString(xml_node);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("ERROR: Extremely old browser");
            return "";
        }
    }

    // display in alert box
    alert(xml_to_string(my_xml));

    // display in an XHTML element
    document.getElementById("my-element").innerHTML = xml_to_string(my_xml);
-->
</script>
```

Comment: From the Mozilla Developer Center: "XMLSerializer is mainly useful for applications and extensions based on Mozilla platform. While it's available to web pages, it's not part of any standard and level of support in other browsers is unknown."

Comment: XMLSerializer alone won't work in all browsers, hence the if statement.  The function should work in all browsers -- at least all modern browsers (MSIE6+,etc)

Comment: Does the function return HTML encoded XML, or just an XML string? I believe setting innerHTML to an XML string would result in the rendering problem the OP is trying to work around.

Answer (score 6):

When you don't want to use a whole JavaScript framework just for this...

```
function insertLiteral(literalString, targetElement)
{
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(literalString);
    targetElement.appendChild(textNode)
    return textNode;
}

// test it (for the example, I assume #targetDiv is there but empty)
var xmlString = "<this><is_some><xml with='attributes' /></is_some></this>";
var targetElement = document.getElementById("targetDiv");
var xmlTextNode = insertLiteral(xmlString, targetElement);
```

`#targetDiv` could be styled using CSS:

```
#targetDiv {
  font-family: fixed;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. [createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have to escape the characters that the HTML parser will interpret as markup: <, >, &, and in some cases " and '

Core JavaScript doesn't provide this for you, but many of the add-on libraries do.

For example, Prototype has: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/escapeHTML

Answer (score 2):

One technique would be to use two iframe elements with the src attribute set to the corresponding xml file available from the server (assuming it is exposed through a virtual directory):

```
<iframe src="/myapp/Document1.xml"><iframe src="/myapp/Document2.xml">
```

Alternatively, you could potentially use an AJAX-type request to retrieve the xml documents and then embed them in the HTML document dynamically using something like:

```
getElementById("myDiv").innerText = ajax.response;
```

Comment: the problem is XML doesn't render correctly in most browsers, all the brackets and attributes disappear, leaving you with text that doesn't look like xml

Comment: Both of those techniques should display it fine. Note that the second technique uses "innerText" and not "innerHTML", otherwise what you describe would occur.

Comment: Also note that if you are wanting to embed XML into an HTML document prior to sending it to a client, you can leverage ASP (assuming an IIS server) to encode the xml so it displays properly, using something like: <%= Server.HTMLEncode(sValue) %>

Comment: @Daniel: True, using document.createTextNode would likely be a more cross-browser compatible way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way I found to display XML as Text on the same page for copy and paste:

```
var xml = document.getElementById('svg_element').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('svg_pre').innerText = xml;
```

Comment: This works for me relpaced .innerHTML to .innerText it accepts xml/html