# XML attribute becomes lower case when appending to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

Is there a way to keep the XML `attribute` to be pascal case "LateProcessing" when appending XML into the DOM? The code below shows that the attribute `LateProcessing="true"` however once the XML has appended into the DOM it becomes lower case `lateprocessing="true"`.

```js
var jObj = {
  "Smart Shoes": {
    "Product": "Smart Shoes",
    "Price": 24.99,
    "Quantity": "1x "
  },
  "Denim Jeans": {
    "Product": "Denim Jeans",
    "Price": 30,
    "Quantity": "1x "
  }
}
var xmlString = '<xml id="POSCMD" LateProcessing="true"><commands><injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_CLEAR"/>';

for (var item in jObj) {
  if (jObj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    xmlString += '<injectdata type="literal" data="' + jObj[item].Price + '"/>'; // I don't know where you got UPC from
    xmlString += '<injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_UPC"/>'
  }
}

xmlString += '</commands></xml>';

$('body').append(xmlString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: This is due to the browser's HTML renderer. Best practices state that HTML should be all lowercase, hence the string is output to the DOM as such. When viewed as a plain string using `console.log()`, or better yet, in an actual XML viewer, then the casing will not be affected.

Comment: Yeah, viewing it in console.log or source code is fine. So there's no way around it?

Comment: No, you can't just put XML in to the DOM as it will be treated like HTML, however there's a couple of workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349250/how-to-display-xml-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to add XML to the HTML DOM. HTML normalizes the case of element names, XML does not. It's not clear why you are trying to do this, so I can't suggest what you should be doing instead, all I can say is that it's not a good thing to do.

Constructing lexical XML by string concatenation and then parsing it is not good practice either. Especially if you make no attempt to apply escaping to special characters such as `&` and `<` and `"` that might appear in the variable strings.